# OCIEnvCreate fails with Segmentation Fault, C++ application upgrade from Oracle 10g to 11g2

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, oracle-call-interface, oracle11gr2

C++ gurus, I'm completely baffled by the behavior of some code, and I need as much help as possible to sort it out.

I'm posting a C++ application from Oracle 10g to 11g2, and the code fails to connect to the Oracle database. In fact, it issues a Segmentation Fault without throwing a core, and I can't figure out what the problem is because the code runs perfectly fine with Oracle 10g.

```
(*oci)->status = OCIInitialize(OCI_OBJECT, 0, 0, 0, 0);
(*oci)->status = OCIEnvInit(&(*oci)->envhp, OCI_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
```

I just replaced both the calls by `OCIEnvCreate` (following Oracle documentation)

The DBX trace clearly points out that the process fails at the `OCIEnvCreate` function call. If it helps, here's the sequence of calls the code makes:

## DBX Output

```
t@6 (l@6) signal SEGV (no mapping at the fault address) in ltzGetFileContentVer at 0xfd5994d4

0xfd5994d4: ltzGetFileContentVer+0x0008:        ld       [%o0], %g4
Current function is oci_initialize

(dbx) where
current thread: t@6
  [1] ltzGetFileContentVer(0xfbe80000, 0xfb9faf08, 0xfeccbda4, 0x0, 0xa70f04, 0xa6fea0), at 0xfd5994d4

  [2] lditzver(0xfbe80000, 0x0, 0xfb9faf08, 0xfb9faf0a, 0x400, 0x0), at 0xfd5620cc

  [3] kpuiniPG(0x270cf8, 0x1, 0xfebf76dc, 0xfe9f7ca8, 0xfe9f792c, 0x106c), at 0xfcc49b9c

  [4] kpuinit0(0x1c2790, 0x20, 0xfe9be6fc, 0x270798, 0xfea43a90, 0xfcc495c4), at 0xfcc47808

  [5] kpuenvcr(0x0, 0x1400, 0x0, 0x1b4000, 0x0, 0x40), at 0xfcc4659c

  [6] OCIEnvCreate(0x1c2790, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x20000), at 0xfcadb48c

=>[7] oci_initialize(oci = 0x2070f0), line 150 in "oci_helper.c"
```

## Code

```
int oci_initialize(oci_helper_t** oci)
{
  if (NULL == oci)
    return OCIHELP_INVALID_ARGUMENT;

  *oci = (oci_helper_t*)malloc(sizeof(oci_helper_t));

  if (NULL == *oci)
  return OCIHELP_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY;

  (*oci)->status = OCIEnvCreate(&(*oci)->envhp,(ub4) OCI_THREADED | OCI_OBJECT,0,0,0,0,0,0);
  if ((*oci)->status != OCI_SUCCESS) {
    return OCIHELP_CALL_ERROR;
  }

  (*oci)->status = OCIHandleAlloc((*oci)->envhp, (void*)&(*oci)->errhp, OCI_HTYPE_ERROR, 0, 0);
  if ((*oci)->status != OCI_SUCCESS)
    return OCIHELP_CALL_ERROR;

  (*oci)->status = OCIHandleAlloc((*oci)->envhp, (void*)&(*oci)->srvhp, OCI_HTYPE_SERVER, 0, 0);
  if ((*oci)->status != OCI_SUCCESS)
    return OCIHELP_CALL_ERROR;

  (*oci)->status = OCIDescriptorAlloc((*oci)->envhp, (void*)&(*oci)->msgprop, OCI_DTYPE_AQMSG_PROPERTIES, 0, 0);
  if ((*oci)->status != OCI_SUCCESS)
    return OCIHELP_CALL_ERROR;

  return OCIHELP_CALL_OK;
}
```

Comment: What is the OS? Try to compare output from ldd, echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH, echo $ORACLE_HOME. Is it possible you still use some 10g libs?

Comment: Solaris 10 is the OS. $LD_LIBRARY_PATH, $LD_LIBRARY_PATH_32 $ORACLE_HOME is set fine, pointing to the 11g2 libraries. Even ldd o/p is fine. Have compiled the application pointing to 32 bit client installation of Oracle 11g2 using Sunstudio12 CC/cc compilers.
App currently do not support 64 bit libraries and unlike Oracle 10g (which had $ORACLE_HOME/lib32 directory) we do not have 32 bit libraries for the server installation.
So we had to do a client installation as well and C++ application is compiled using the 32 bit client installation